# Handling table with two classes to fit a simple classifier

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, regression

I have this dataframe with euclidean distances:
[image: Dataframe]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'O1': [0.0, 1.7, 1.4, 0.4, 2.2, 3.7, 5.2, 0.2, 4.3, 6.8, 6.0],
    'O2': [1.7, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.3, 2.6, 4.5, 1.8, 3.2, 5.9, 5.2],
    'O3': [1.4, 1.0, 0.0, 1.7, 0.9, 2.4, 4.1, 1.5, 3.0, 5.5, 4.8],
    'O4': [0.4, 2.0, 1.7, 0.0, 2.6, 4.0, 5.5, 0.3, 4.6, 7.1, 6.3],
    'O5': [2.2, 1.3, 0.9, 2.6, 0.0, 1.7, 3.4, 2.4, 2.1, 4.8, 4.1],
    'O6': [3.7, 2.6, 2.4, 4.0, 1.7, 0.0, 2.0, 3.8, 1.6, 3.3, 2.7],
    'O7': [5.2, 4.5, 4.1, 5.5, 3.4, 2.0, 0.0, 5.4, 2.5, 1.6, 0.9],
    'O8': [0.2, 1.8, 1.5, 0.3, 2.4, 3.8, 5.4, 0.0, 4.4, 6.9, 6.1],
    'O9': [4.3, 3.2, 3.0, 4.6, 2.1, 1.6, 2.5, 4.4, 0.0, 3.4, 2.9],
    'O10':[6.8, 5.9, 5.5, 7.1, 4.8, 3.3, 1.6, 6.9, 3.4, 0.0, 1.0],
    'O11': [6.0, 5.2, 4.8, 6.3, 4.1, 2.7, 0.9, 6.1, 2.9, 1.0, 0.0]
})
```

Whereas O1, O2, O3, O4, O5, O6, O7, O8 is class 0 and O9, O10 and O11 is class 1.

I want to change the dataframe above to a dataframe with columns: `x`, `y` and `class`. So I am able to split into train and test sets to then fit a simple classifier.

I am confused how I can achieve dataframe described above. How is this performed in python? Is it possible?

Steps afterwards when dataframe is achieved:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import seaborn as sns

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25)

model = GaussianNB()

model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

y_proba = model.predict_proba(X_test)

sns.scatterplot(x = X_test['x'], y = X_test['y'], hue = y_pred)
```

Comment: What values should go into the columns `x`, `y`? You're probably looking for `df.melt()`

Comment: @ozacha thanks I'll look into that! That is exactly the problem, I am confused how the x and y is defined

Answer (score 0):

You mainly want to include the point name as an additional column in the dataframe. Here I am using point indices as `x` and `y`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    1: [0.0, 1.7, 1.4, 0.4, 2.2, 3.7, 5.2, 0.2, 4.3, 6.8, 6.0],
    2: [1.7, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.3, 2.6, 4.5, 1.8, 3.2, 5.9, 5.2],
    3: [1.4, 1.0, 0.0, 1.7, 0.9, 2.4, 4.1, 1.5, 3.0, 5.5, 4.8],
    4: [0.4, 2.0, 1.7, 0.0, 2.6, 4.0, 5.5, 0.3, 4.6, 7.1, 6.3],
    5: [2.2, 1.3, 0.9, 2.6, 0.0, 1.7, 3.4, 2.4, 2.1, 4.8, 4.1],
    6: [3.7, 2.6, 2.4, 4.0, 1.7, 0.0, 2.0, 3.8, 1.6, 3.3, 2.7],
    7: [5.2, 4.5, 4.1, 5.5, 3.4, 2.0, 0.0, 5.4, 2.5, 1.6, 0.9],
    8: [0.2, 1.8, 1.5, 0.3, 2.4, 3.8, 5.4, 0.0, 4.4, 6.9, 6.1],
    9: [4.3, 3.2, 3.0, 4.6, 2.1, 1.6, 2.5, 4.4, 0.0, 3.4, 2.9],
    10: [6.8, 5.9, 5.5, 7.1, 4.8, 3.3, 1.6, 6.9, 3.4, 0.0, 1.0],
    11: [6.0, 5.2, 4.8, 6.3, 4.1, 2.7, 0.9, 6.1, 2.9, 1.0, 0.0]
})
```

That allows you to reshape the dataframe to your desired form:

```
model_df = df.melt(id_vars='x', var_name='y', value_name='distance')
```

Finally, define a class e.g. using:

```
def assign_class(x):
    return 0 if x <= 8 else 1

model_df["class_x"] = model_df["x"].apply(assign_class),
model_df["class_y"] = model_df["y"].apply(assign_class)
```

This will give you a dataframe that you can pass to the model. Note that the input matrix is symmetric, so you may want to only keep unique records (drop [y, x] if you already have [x, y]).